# How do I plot a function with different values of various parameters on gnuplot?

Tags: plot, gnuplot, parametric-equations

I want to plot this parametric funtion

```
 x(t)=a+(n/w)*(cos(w*t)-1)-((g/w**2)*sin(l)-m/w)*(sin(w*t)+(g*t/w)*sin(l))

 y(t)=b+((g/w**2)*sin(l)-m/w)*(cos(w*t)-1)+(n/w)*sin(w*t)
```

But I have various parameters a,b,m,n,w,k,g y I want to vary a,b,m,n,w,k parameters. g=7

I don't know how do it.

However i intended:

`plot for [a=1:0],[b=1:0],[n=0:1],[m=1:0],[g=7:7],[w=2*pi*3:2*pi*2] x(t),y(t)`

I appreciate your help. thanks!

Comment: Last term in `y(t)` should be `sin(w*t)` please [edit]

Comment: 1st issue, the parameters that you have used in the definitions are `a, b, g, l, m, n, w` — you haven;t named `l` in the question but you have introduced a spurious `y` that is not a parameter nut a dependent variable, please [edit] ፨ 2nd issue, you have a loop for `w` in which the required step is not defined... would you like a step of `pi`? of `pi/2`? of `2*pi`? please [edit] the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what regards multiple `for` in a single `plot` command, the syntax is documented in the inline help of `gnuplot`

> ```
>  Nested iteration is supported:
>
>        set for [i=1:9] for [j=1:9] label i*10+j sprintf("%d",i*10+j) at i,j
> ```

E.g.,

```
gnuplot> plot for[a=0:1] for[b=0:1] 1+a*x+b*x*x
```

[image: plot for[a=0:1] for[b=0:1] 1+a*x+b*x*x]

---

You could do now what you want except for a further problem: in `gnuplot` numeric loops variables have only integer values, e.g.,

```
gnuplot> plot for [s=3.2:9.3:2.9] x title sprintf("%f", s)
```

[image: plot for [s=3.2:9.3:2.9] x title sprintf("%f", s)]

so your loop on `w` is impossible, you have to devise a different strategy.

With the provision that I don't know what value you want to assign to `l` (I've used `l=1`) and also that I don't know the step on `w`, here it is a possible implementation where the tricks are ❶ define a function that gives you the values of `w` in terms of an integer variable and ❷ define `x` and `y` *also* in terms of this auxiliary variable

```
gnuplot> set parametric
gnuplot> w(k) = 2*pi*k
gnuplot> x(t, k)=a+(n/w(k))*(cos(w(k)*t)-1)-((g/w(k)**2)*sin(l)-m/w(k))*(sin(w(k)*t)+(g*t/w(k))*sin(l))
gnuplot> y(t, k) = b + ((g/w(k)**2)*sin(l)-m/w(k))*(cos(w(k)*t)-1)+(n/w(k))*sin(w(k)*t)
gnuplot> g = 7 ; l = 1
gnuplot> plot for[a=0:1] for[b=0:1] for[m=0:1] for[n=0:1] for[k=2:3] x(t,k), y(t,k) title sprintf("%d,%d,%d,%d,%d", a,b,n,m,k)
```

[image: strange plots]